# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found:

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
    batch_size = 32
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=122, padding="same",activation="relu",input_shape=(122, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=(5)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False))) 
    model.add(Reshape((128, 1), input_shape = (128, )))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=(5)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))) 
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(5))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**While running the above model, I am facing this issue:**
[image]

**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix `keras` and `tensorflow.keras`. They're two different frameworks that are not compatible.

Either you import **everything** `from keras` or you import **everything** from `tensorflow.keras`.